# Center a navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am using a template and I am trying to center that navigation bar because I moved the logo. Here is the CSS

```
/* Menu */
.menu{float:right; padding:14px 20px 0 0;}
.menu ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0px;}
.menu ul * {margin:0; padding:0;}
.menu ul li {position:relative; float:left; padding:0 20px 0 20px; height:35px;}
.menu ul li a{font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif;color:#2b2b2b; font-size:16px;}
.menu ul li.selected a{color:#e93139;}
.menu ul li a:hover{color:#e93139;}

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">competition</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">workshops</a></li>

        <li><a href="blog.html">travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
 </div>
```

How do I center this menu?

Comment: Your menu is floating right, so it's supposed to stick to the right? It would be best if you can provide a snippet or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
.menu {
  float: right;
}
```

Add

```
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzVpmB?editors=1100).

`text-align: center` set on `.menu` applies to textual content of this element, but also to all it's inline or inline-block children. This is why we give `display: inline-block` to `.menu ul`.

Comment: when I use display: inline-block; the menu goes drops underneath the slider which is below the menu

Comment: @MikeOwens: Remove `height: 140px;` from `#header`.

Comment: Please explain WHY this is **the** solution

Comment: @Kukeltje: You are absolutely right, I've added appropriate explanation. I just forgot to include it first, as I moved to answering another question. I normally never post a bare code without a word of comment about it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the first two lines of css like this:

```
/* Menu */
.menu{padding:14px 20px 0 0; text-align:center}
.menu ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0px; display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css on the menu class:

```
display: table;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

That will center anything, even without specifying the Width.

Answer (score -1):

Change your css to this

```
body{margin:0, padding:0;}
.menu{position:relative; left:15%; margin:auto;}
.menu ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0px;}
.menu ul * {margin:0; padding:0;}
.menu ul li {display:inline; padding:0 20px 0 20px; height:35px;}
.menu ul li a{font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif;color:#2b2b2b; font-size:16px;}
.menu ul li.selected a{color:#e93139;}
.menu ul li a:hover{color:#e93139;}
```

Comment: Compatibility Notes: The <div> align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. (it still works but it's deprecated)

Comment: Also Google uses <center> tag on it's homepage and it works well but it's deprecated since 1999

Comment: Thanks. Changed it to css styling only

Answer (score -1):

Change the `.menu` class to this:

```
.menu{ padding:14px 20px 0 0; margin:auto; width:50%;}
```

Comment: This can easily break menu in 2 or more lines

Comment: and info on WHY this is a solution, some textual explanation